# How to add date filter to product collection

Tags: product-collection, collection-filtering, date, custom-collection

I was wondering if there is any way to add a date filter to a product collection.
What i am trying to do: I have a collection for new products, i need to add a filter to it so it filter the products by date. i dont need all days just three past days. The idea is just like layered navigation just the option must be three past days and they mus be generated dynamically.
Note: The date mus be selected in frontend by the user.
THanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure about your actual use case, but to filter a product collection so that it only returns products created within the last 3 days do as follows

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('gt' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('-3 day'))));
```

Comment: No i want to select the date in frontend.

Comment: Well that's entirely dependent on your frontend implementation. Perhaps an ajax request to a controller, gets given the date, converts it using strtotime (as above) to show past X days, then loads and returns the product data you need.

Comment: Well thank you for the answer but i need a little bit help implementing it. Its beyond my magento knowledge. I can make the controller but i dont know how to create the frontend part and send data with ajax request.